# Expected an expression, a rookie mistake?

Tags: c++

Im rather new to programming and im currently working on a homework assignment to create a toolkit for linked lists.

Im getting an error "Expected an expression" as im trying to test one of the functions ive created.

```
template<class T> 
class LLToolkit
{
public:
    LLToolkit<T>::initNode(T* head, T x)                
    {
        head->info = x;
        head->next = NULL;
    };

//some other functions
};

    int main()
{
    LLToolkit<Node> n1;

    n1.initNode(n1*,1); //Exprected an expression
}
```

I know its probably some rookie-mistake and ive tried to search the forum to find an answer to this, but im not sure if it confuses me more than it helps :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Taking the address of `n1` is done with `&n1`, not `n1*`.

`n1*` does not have any meaning in the given context, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `n1.initNode(n1*,1);`  you should put: `n1.initNode(&n1,1);` 
The `n1*` is an incorrect expression, to get the pointer you should use `&n1`.

Answer (score 0):

1.You don't need `LLToolkit<T>::` for the inside class defination of `initNode`:

```
template<class T> 
class LLToolkit
{
public:
    initNode(T* head, T x)                
    {
        head->info = x;
        head->next = NULL;
    };

//some other functions
};
```

2.`initNode` 's 1st parameter is `T*`, 2nd parameter is `T`, according to `LLToolkit<Node> n1;`, you should pass `Node*` and `Node` for `n1.initNode`.